# I cant figure out what i did wrong in this if statement inside of and def function

Tags: python, function, if-statement, input

Whenever i run the program and type in any of the boy commands its outputs correctly, but if i use the girl commands then it outputs with error, and is there an easier way to write this entire code.

```
def create_a_character():
    gender = input("What's the gender?: ")
    if gender.lower() in ['boy', 'man', 'male']:
        print("Its a boy")
    elif gender.lower() in ['girl', 'woman', 'female']:
        print ("Its a girl")
    else:
        print("error")
    create_a_character()
create_a_character()
```

Comment: btw i have the create_a_character() under the print("error") indented correctly in my code

Comment: Hey, I just tried it and it's working correctly at my end. Python 3.7

Comment: Working fine for me.

Comment: What is the error u are getting ?

Comment: Hello Fonntaine. So you want an endless program that asks for a gender. Your program seems ok. You could have used a while True loop.

Comment: i only want it to redo the gender thing if it says error

Comment: and on vs code it comes out with error for the femal part

Comment: How about you tell us what the error is, exactly?

Comment: it literally says error, it skips the elif and goes to the else

Comment: As we can't recreate it, it's going to be impossible to tell you what the problem is. If you can use the debugger in VScode, try to use the debugging tools to see what's going on. If not, at least print out `gender.lower()` so you can see for yourself what you've been comparing. Also, you don't redo a function by calling it from within itself, you really should put the code inside a while loop so that you can repeat the loop if it's an error or `break` out of the loop if it's successful.

Comment: Code seems good. Maybe your input `girl` is not right (maybe there is an invisible space). Try `gender.strip().lower()` to remove spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive call, which is not a good idea here.
You could try this:

```
def create_a_character():
    gender = input("What's the gender?: ")
    if gender.lower() in ['boy', 'man', 'male']:
       return "Its a boy"
    elif gender.lower() in ['girl', 'woman', 'female']:
       return "Its a girl"
    else:
       return "error"
while True:
  ch_str=create_a_character()
  if ch_str!="error":
     break

print(ch_str)
```